# Plotly scatter3d aspectmode not consistent across axes

Tags: python, plotly

Below is my plotly figure which can be seen here. I'm trying to get my image to show up as the 16x9 aspect ratio as stated within the axes ranges. However, when I set the `aspectmode` to `data` I get an extremely elongated plot that doesn't appear to match the correct aspect ratio.

[image: Plot showing elogated graph where y axis is 2-4x larger than the z axis.]

```
fig = go.Figure(
    data = go.Scatter3d(
        x=df['frame'], 
        y=df['x'], 
        z=df['y'],
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(
            color=clusters.labels_,
            colorscale="Cividis",
            opacity=0.8
        )
    )
)
fig['layout']['scene']['aspectmode'] = "data"
fig['layout']['scene']['zaxis']['range'] = [1080, 0]
fig['layout']['scene']['yaxis']['range'] = [0, 1920]
fig.show()
```

Comment: Isn't it necessary to specify not only the y-axis and z-axis, but also the x-axis as well?

Comment: I tried specifying it but it didn't change the result. I didn't specify it to begin with because i don't care about the aspect ratio relationship between the x & z or x & y axes.

Comment: @AustinUlfers did you ever find a solution? Dealing with same problem.

Comment: @twhughes Unfortunately, I did not. I just dealt with it. If you upvote it, it might help bring this post to the surface.

Comment: @AustinUlfers I'm having the same issue. I posted on the same Plotly thread too... we'll see if anything happens